# Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function that is loosely based on this example 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/image-sharp

Today, when deploying some small changes it gave me this warning

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
 Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
```

so I did the upgrade, which upgraded firebase-functions from ^1.0.3 to ^2.0.0

since then have been getting this when running the function

```
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

instead of the usual

```
Function execution took 10 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

I started stripping down my function but even going down to bare bones it was still getting the error.

I then started a new project used the example function as is and it behaves exactly the same way. With firebase-functions ^2.0.0 it gives the timeout error but with ^1.0.0 it works fine.

Is this a known issue?

Thanks

Here is the example code

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
  }

  // Get the file name.
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
  if (fileName.startsWith('thumb_')) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    return null;
  }

  // Download file from bucket.
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);

  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };
  // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
  const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
  const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
  // Create write stream for uploading thumbnail
  const thumbnailUploadStream = bucket.file(thumbFilePath).createWriteStream({metadata});

  // Create Sharp pipeline for resizing the image and use pipe to read from bucket read stream
  const pipeline = sharp();
  pipeline
    .resize(THUMB_MAX_WIDTH, THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT)
    .max()
    .pipe(thumbnailUploadStream);

  bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);

  const streamAsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    thumbnailUploadStream.on('finish', resolve).on('error', reject));

  return streamAsPromise.then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created successfully');
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Without showing the code of your function, there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: Hi Doug as I described it is loosely based on the example I sent. Then I went back to running the example and was able to recreate the problem by updating to 2.0.0 of firebase-functions

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: See https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18032

Comment: You can now install v2.0.1 to address the issue.

Comment: I can confirm upgrading to v2.0.1 has fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I was going to comment but it requires me 50+ reputations.....

Anyway, I am experiencing the same problem:

```
exports.sendNotificationForMessage = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const newMessage = snap.data();
  const messageContent = newMessage.text;
  const senderName = newMessage.senderDisplayName;
  const senderId = newMessage.senderId;
  const chatroomId = context.params.chatroomId;
  console.log(newMessage)

  return true;
});
```

It finished with status timeout.

If it's a problem with firebase-function 2.0, what is the command to downgrade it back to version 1.x? Googled about it but no luck.

Comment: They've recently released [v2.0.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases). You can upgrade to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try calling resolve and reject with ():

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
  }
  // Get the file name.
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
  if (fileName.startsWith('thumb_')) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    return null;
  }
  // Download file from bucket.
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };
  // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
  const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
  const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
  // Create write stream for uploading thumbnail
  const thumbnailUploadStream = bucket.file(thumbFilePath).createWriteStream({metadata});
  // Create Sharp pipeline for resizing the image and use pipe to read from bucket read stream
  const pipeline = sharp();
  pipeline.resize(THUMB_MAX_WIDTH, THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT).max().pipe(thumbnailUploadStream);
  bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);
  const streamAsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    thumbnailUploadStream.on('finish', resolve()).on('error', reject()));
  return streamAsPromise.then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created successfully');
    return null;
  });
});
```