# Firebase Cloud Function Timeout When Creating Directory (generateThumbnail Example)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a (very slightly) modified version of the generateThumbnail Firebase Cloud Function found in the [Firebase Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js). The function was working correctly at one point, and now it will time out every time it is called. I haven't made any changes to the function or to the rules for my storage bucket. The rules are the default ones that check for authentication. After adding some logging I can see that it never makes it past this line:

`await file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});`

The image file I am testing with is a 15.21KB PNG. The timeout of the function happens after ~60000 ms (default). There is no error in the logs, only the timeout.

Any suggestions as to why it started timing out all of the sudden? Or how to debug this single call further?

- Node: 14
- Firebase Admin: 9.8.0
- Firebase Functions: 3.14.1

**EDITS**

I have deployed a minimum reproducable function and am seeing the same results.

```
exports.newGenerateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const filePath = object.name;
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
  // Cloud Storage files.
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);

  functions.logger.log('Creating Temp Directory');
  await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);
  functions.logger.log('Temp Directory Created');

  functions.logger.log('Downloading File');
  await file.download({ destination: tempLocalFile });
  functions.logger.log('File Downloaded');

  functions.logger.log('Removing File');
  fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
  functions.logger.log('File Deleted');

  return true;
});
```

The logs show this

[image: Logs]

Comment: Try using promise

Comment: Using a promise instead does not change anything.

Comment: Hi, As you have mentioned ```I have a (very slightly) modified version of the generateThumbnail Firebase Cloud Function found in the Firebase Github repo```, can you provide the code that you have modified, I tried to reproduce at my end, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: The changes are to the paths / file names. I will update my question with minimum reproducable code later today. Thanks

Comment: I updated my question with a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue using your code, but it is working fine for me without any timeout as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSP2i.png).

I cross checked my versions with yours, I am using Node: 16.6, Firebase: 10.2.1, Firebase Functions: 3.16

It may be because of the version as it is seen in the past as well, as shown in the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522227/function-execution-took-60002-ms-finished-with-status-timeout). So I suggest you upgrade your version and try again, it might help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Took a while to follow up on this, but I updated both firebase-admin and firebase-functions to their latest versions. Also updated my node engine to 16. Still seeing the same result.

Comment: I am not sure what might be the problem in your case, I suggest you to check the IAM permissions, also try to trigger the function on some other bucket.